# Is it possible to create SwiftIO Namespace programmatically?

Tags: swiftui

I am creating scrollview as follows and I want to go requested button in array
using Namespace variable.

I saw it used to to go to bottom or top of scrollview but Namespace variables created manually. Because I want to go any button might requested I want to create Namespace
for every item in scrollview not only for top or bottom one.

Is it possible to create Namespace ID using index somehow valueIndex in that case.
I hope it would be something like that **selectIndex as Namespace**.

```
     ScrollViewReader { proxy in
                            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: true){
                                LazyHStack() {
                                    ForEach(0..<listValues[valueIndex].count, id: \.self) { selectIndex in
                                        
                                        Button(action: {
                                            
                                            dump(selectIndex)
                                            
                                        }){
                                            Text(listValues[valueIndex][selectIndex])
                                                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                                                .background(Color.red)
                                                .frame(width: w2 * 0.5 * 0.5, height: 40)
                                        } .id(**selectIndex as Namespace**)
                                        
                                    }.background(Color.gray)
                                    
                                }
                            }.frame(width: w2 * 0.5 * 0.5, height: 40)
                        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a `NameSpace` in a `ScrollViewReader`, you just need to use any `Hashable` to identify the place you want to scroll to. You didn't give a  [Minimal Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and I couldn't find a straightforward scroll to answer, so I made a basic one to show you how it is done. Please see the comments.

```
// You should always use an Identifiable in a ForEach. For
// a `scrollTo()`, you only need a `Hashable` `.id()`, so
// this struct has been conformed to Hashable.
struct ScrollItem: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id = UUID()
    var name: String
}


struct ScrollToView: View {
    let scrollItems: [ScrollItem] = Array(0..<100).map( { ScrollItem(name: "Row " + $0.description) })
    @State var selectedItem: ScrollItem?
    
    var body: some View{
        ScrollViewReader{ scrollReader in
            VStack {
                // This button scrolls the selected row to the top, or as high as it can go
                Button {
                    withAnimation {
                        scrollReader.scrollTo(selectedItem, anchor: .top)
                    }
                } label: {
                    Text(selectedItem != nil ? "Scroll \(selectedItem!.name) To Top" : "Select Row")
                }
                
                List {
                    // ScrollItem is Identifiable, so you do not need to designate id:
                    ForEach(scrollItems) { item in
                        Text(item.name)
                            .padding()
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 50, alignment: .leading)
                        // If the row is selected, this gives a colored background
                            .background(
                                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)
                                    .fill(selectedItem == item ? Color.yellow.opacity(0.4) : Color.clear)
                            )
                            .contentShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15))
                        // This allows you to select and deselect the row
                            .onTapGesture {
                                if selectedItem == item {
                                    selectedItem = nil
                                } else {
                                    selectedItem = item
                                }
                            }
                        // ScrollItem conforms to Hashable, so it can be used as the .id()
                            .id(item)
                    }
                }
                
                // This button scrolls the selected row to the bottom, or as low as it can go
                Button {
                    withAnimation {
                        scrollReader.scrollTo(selectedItem, anchor: .bottom)
                    }
                } label: {
                    Text(selectedItem != nil ? "Scroll \(selectedItem!.name) To Bottom" : "Select Row")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```